# File field losses its style after click on edit button using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a big issue while using UpdatePanel in asp.net.I have one file field which is like below image before user click on edit button to update the row value.

[image]

Once the edit button is clicked it looks like below simple input file format.

[image]

I am explaining my code below.

> banner.aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>

 <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6 bannerimagefile">
                                                <label for="title" accesskey="T"><span class="required">*</span> Title</label>
                                                <div id="errTitle" style="display:none;" runat="server"></div> 
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBnrTitle" runat="server" size="30" value="" ></asp:TextBox>
                                                <label for="status" accesskey="S"><span class="required">*</span> Status</label>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="bnrStatus" runat="server" >
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Select your status" Value="enable" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Enable" Value="enable"></asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Disable" Value="disable"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList> 
                                                <label for="insertimage" accesskey="B"><span class="required">*</span> Banner Image</label>
                                                <asp:FileUpload runat="server" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="insertimage" id="FileUpload1" onchange="previewFile()" />
                                                <label for="bannerimage" accesskey="V"><span class="required">*</span> View Image</label>
                                                <div style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                                                    <asp:Image ID="bnrimgPhoto" runat="server" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;"   />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label for="shortdes" accesskey="V"><span class="required">*</span> Short Description</label>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="bnrshortdes" runat="server" size="30" value="" ></asp:TextBox>
                                                <div id="bnrShtdesErrDiv" style="display:none;" runat="server"></div>
                                                <label for="description" accesskey="D"><span class="required">*</span> Description</label>
                                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBnrDesc" runat="server" name="description" cols="40" Rows="7" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                                 <div id="bnrDesErrDiv" style="display:none;" runat="server"></div>
                                                 <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" class="submit" ID="bnrSubmit" OnClick="bnrSubmit_Click" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--end_1st_banner_add_div-->
                            <!--2nd_list_banner_view_div-->
                            <div class="widget-area">
                                <h2 class="widget-title"><strong>Banner List</strong></h2><asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1"  runat="server" />
                                <div class="streaming-table margin-top-zero padding-top-zero">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                <asp:GridView ID="Bnr_Gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered margin-top-zero" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Bnr_Gridview_OnSelectedIndexChanged"  onrowdeleting="Bnr_Gridview_RowDeleting" DataKeyNames="Bnr_ID"  >
                                <PagerStyle />
                            <Columns>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl. No" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                     <ItemTemplate>
                                       <asp:Label ID="Title" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Bnr_Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                                     </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "/Upload/Banner/" + Convert.ToString(Eval("Bnr_Image")) %>' Height="70" Width="70" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="description" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblRemark" runat="server"
                                            Text='<%# Eval("Bnr_Description").ToString().Length > 100? (Eval("Bnr_Description") as string).Substring(0,100) + " ..." : Eval("Bnr_Description")  %>'
                                            ToolTip='<%# Eval("Bnr_Description") %> '> </asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                     <ItemTemplate>
                                       <asp:Label ID="Status" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Bnr_Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                                     </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" Text="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-original-title="Edit"
                                            CommandName="Select"
                                            runat="server" OnClientClick="resetFileField();"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></asp:LinkButton>

                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDel" Text="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete"
                                            CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Bnr_ID") %>' onclientclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"
                                            runat="server"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>


</ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
  <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="bnrSubmit" />

</Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

> banner.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Bnr_Gridview_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = Bnr_Gridview.SelectedRow;
            string bnrId = Bnr_Gridview.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            txtBnrTitle.Text = (row.FindControl("Title") as Label).Text;
            bnrStatus.SelectedValue = (row.FindControl("Status") as Label).Text;
            bnrimgPhoto.ImageUrl = ((Image)(row.FindControl("Image1"))).ImageUrl;
            txtBnrDesc.Text = (row.FindControl("lblRemark") as Label).Text;
            HiddenField1.Value = bnrId;
            bnrSubmit.Text = "Update";
        }
```

When i removed UpdatePanel it is working fine.But here i need when user will click on edit link with UpdatePanel the file field should display like the first image given above.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: that is file upload right

Comment: @Nikolay:I am getting probelm in this line`<asp:FileUpload runat="server" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="insertimage" id="FileUpload1" onchange="previewFile()" />`.

Comment: that is problem with the update panel I think this topic can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494731/server-control-lost-its-css-style-when-update-panel-is-used

Comment: Any other solution ?

Comment: well have you try  to asynpostback on the linkbutton

Comment: @Nikolay: I used `AsyncPostBackTrigger` but it did not give any result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83738/discussion-between-satya-and-nikolay).